# charging one battery and discharging another battery simultaneously

Tags: battery-charging

I have two 12v 7.2ah lead acid battery. The initial voltages of the first and second are 12v and 8v. If I connect four 5watt 12v led lamps to the first and a 100w solar panel giving approx. 12v to the second. What will happen first, the voltage of the first will come to 8 or the voltage of the second will come to 12. Im not talking about fully charging or discharging them. Secondly, is using a 100w solar panel for charging and four bulbs for discharging okay for the batteries.

Comment: Well, if you discharge one battery with a 20W load while charging another identical battery with 100W power source, then all bets are on charging going on faster. Was that your question?

Answer (score 3):

1. You should never allow a lead-acid battery to discharge to less than
   10 volts.
2. Lead-acid battery capacity is usually specified at a discharge rate
   of \$\frac{C}{10}\$. Then since 20 watts taken from the battery will drain it
   at a rate of about 1.7 amperes and, since the rate for C, at \$
   \frac{7.2Ah}{10} \$ is 720 milliamperes, you'll get something less
   than 7.2Ah out of the battery.
3. If your PV array can truly pump 100 watts into the discharged
   battery while charging it, then the charging current will be about
   8.3 amperes which may well be more than a small battery can handle.

Check the battery's data sheet to be sure, and to learn more, **[go here.](http://batteryuniversity.com/)**